# When does the matrix $R$ fail to be invertible in the $QR$ decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my class, we say that the $QR$ decomposition of a $n \times  m$ matrix $A$ is when $A = QR$ and $R$ is invertible and upper triangular and $Q$ has the property that $Q^T Q = I$. I looked at other sources online, and other people do not require that the matrix $R$ is invertible. I found examples of square matrices where the $R$ matrix failed to be invertible. Is there an example of a rectangular matrix where $R$ fails to be invertible?

Comment: A $QR$ factorization always exists, regardless of the matrix $A$ being invertible or even square. Then $R$ is going to be invertible iff $A$ is invertible.

Comment: @totoro How can you prove that? I have a matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -2 & 1 \\ 1  &3 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 &  5\end{bmatrix}$ which is non invertible, and according to my class' book, the $R$ matrix is $R = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2}  & 2\sqrt{2} &  3\sqrt{2} \\ 0 & \sqrt{6} &  -\sqrt{6} \\ 0 &  0 & 2 \end{bmatrix} $. But that $R$ is invertible but $A$ is not?

Comment: I am not sure what are the shapes of those matrices. Independently of the example, if $Q$ is orthogonal matrix, in particular is square and invertible. Therefore, if $A$ is invertible, then $R=Q^TA$ is invertible.

Comment: In the QR decomposition $A=QR$, the $R$ matrix has the same shape as $A$. That $R$ might be the reduced $R$. They deleted the bunch of zeros at the bottom, one row of zeros in this case. That is done to save space, but it doesn't mean that $A=QR$ for that $R$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Rectangular_matrix)

Comment: @totoro I see. I think since you told me that they removed a row of zeros on that $R$ answers my question.

Comment: Check for the size of the $Q$. It should be a $4\times 4$ matrix, orthogonal, and in particular invertible. Then, the real $R$ should be $4\times 3$ such that you can multiply it by $Q$ from the left and get a $4\times 3$ matrix $A$.

Comment: How can $A$ be invertible or non invertible, since it's not square? There will always exist a pseudoinverse, but never an inverse in the traditional sense, right?

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you a hint:  start with a rectangular matrix that is already upper triangular but is not invertible.